# Error while deleting Network Load Balancer (NLB): Cannot be deleted because it is currently associated with another service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I'm trying to delete a load balancer but receiving below error:

> Cannot be deleted because it is currently associated with another
> service

Followed [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-fix-nlb-associated-with-service/) to reject endpoint connection request first and then tried deleting load balancer, *but still getting same error*.

Screenshots of error messages and steps I followed:

[image: Load balancer delete error]

[image: Reject endpoint connection request]

Wondering what else I'm missing here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After bit of playing with it, I could delete load balancer after I deleted Endpoint service itself.

Steps I took to delete load balancer:

1. Open the Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) console.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Endpoint Services.
3. Review the Network Load Balancer tab for each of your endpoint services to determine whether your Network Load Balancer is associated with an endpoint service.
4. Choose the Endpoint Connections tab to determine which endpoint connections are attached to your endpoint service.
5. For all of the connections that are not in the Rejected state, choose Actions, and then choose Reject endpoint connection request.
6. ***Delete Endpoint Service***
7. Choose the Network Load Balancers tab.
8. Delete the Network Load Balancer.

Comment: Yeah, it can be difficult to kill all connections in a VPC sometimes. Good work!